# C: howto convert a pointer to access it as a multidimensional array

Tags: c

I do have a function call like:

```
int Filter(short* array, short nNumRow, short nNumCol)
```

but inside it I want to handle array like that:

```
array[y][x] = xx;
```

I try to solve this by declaring an array

```
short help[nNumRow][nNumCol];
help = array;
```

but this doesn't work that way. How can I handle that problem without changing function parameter list (this *array is result of a different function that I can't change)? Best of course would be not a copy (of memory) is needed.
Probably another option would be

```
 array[y*nNumCol + x] = xx;
```

but I don't like this calculations. So how to do this best?
Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying you want to declare function parameter as `short* array` but use `array[m][n]`' in function definition?

Comment: Can you show an example for the input for your function?

Comment: If I understand correctly you could use memcpy to do the job you want

Answer (score 8):

> How can I handle that problem without changing function parameter list?

If you can't do that, then you are stuck with the "mangled array" `array[y*nNumCol + x]` notation (which is old style but otherwise ok).

The best and correct solution is to change the function to this:

```
int Filter (short nNumRow, short nNumCol, short array[nNumRow][nNumCol])
{
   ...
   array[x][y] = something;
}
```

---

The last resort, which I would not recommend unless you are maintaining some old crap that can't be changed, is a dirty pointer conversion inside the function. Writing such code requires that you to know exactly what you are doing, because if the types of the actual data or the alignment mismatch, you will get very strange bugs. The below code works and is safe as far as the C language is concerned, but it isn't pretty:

```
// BAD CODE, avoid this solution

#include <stdio.h>

int Filter (short* array, short nNumRow, short nNumCol)
{
  short(*array2D)[nNumCol];            // pointer to array of type short[nNumCol]
  array2D = (short(*)[nNumCol])array;  // dirty pointer conversion

  for(int i=0; i<nNumRow; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<nNumCol; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", array2D[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}

int main (void) 
{
  short array[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };

  Filter((void*)array, 2, 2);
}
```

Comment: I agree your first approach is best and according to the rules but not that has been requested for. The array is a result from some existing code I can't change. The issue with the second example is  you really have to spend memory for the array2D, haven't you?

Comment: @Arno `array2D` is just a pointer, so it will only require memory of typical pointer. In this case it probably fits in CPU register.

Comment: @Arno No and you can't pass arrays by value in C. In the first example, `short array[nNumRow][nNumCol]` "decays" into an array pointer between the lines. In the second example, `short(*array2D)[nNumCol];` is also just an array pointer.

Comment: You are both right, didn't read carefully enough. Thanks! Think I wouldn't get managed this "dirty" pointer conversion on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The best (optimal) way to do that is your own solution:

```
array[y*nNumCol + x] = xx;
```

Fo "beauty" reasons, you may use a function-like macro to access that data:

```
#define arrElement(array,x,y) ((array)[(y)*nNumCol + (x)]]))
```

If you need to apply this trick to only one array, then you can simplify the macro:

```
#define arrElement(x,y) (array[(y)*nNumCol + (x)]]))
```

If the size of the array is not known before the function call, you will need to add some complexity to the macro:

```
#define arrElement(x,y,nNumCol) (array[(y)*(nNumCol) + (x)]]))
```

---

Note: I did not text exactly the statements above, but I used the trick in the past several times, successfully.

---

You can use a pointer-type (as per your question) only if the array always has the same size. Otherwise, you will have to define the pointer-type dynamically at run-time, which is somewhere between difficult and impossible.

---

A sane thing to do is to pass to the function the array size also, and check if the coordinates actually fall inside the array. Otherwise, you may run into undefined behavior, accessing data outside defined range.

Comment: "Otherwise, you will have to define the pointer-type dynamically at run-time, which is somewhere between difficult and impossible". Eh, it's not really that hard. Given the array `int array[x][y]`, a pointer to such an array is `int (*ptr)[x][y]`. Though for convenience when accessing, you'd drop the inner dimension: `int (*ptr)[y]`. And that's it.

Comment: @Lundin: That is perfectly fine if the array has a size known at design time. I remember I tried defining arrays with sizes known only during runtime (i.e. variable / random x and y), and the compiler rejected my attempt.

Comment: Sorry, but your C knowledge is 20 years outdated. The language was changed in the year 1999. Time to study the C99 version and variable-length arrays.

Comment: Also sorry, but it is what is used in the automotive industry, to make sure that the brakes and other stuff always work as expected. OTOH, good point that I should get acquainted with the news :D Tnx for the heads up.

Comment: No, the automotive industry mainly uses C99 or C11 under MISRA-C:2012. They trailed behind and remained reluctant to use C99 until somewhere around 2010, as did I.

Comment: I know about the new MISRA, but it was still not widely adopted the last time I checked. Maybe things have changed "recently", I will not fight you on this.

Comment: MISRA-C is not only widely adopted in all automotive firmware, it is pretty much mandatory nowadays, since you can't pass ISO 26262 ("ASIL") qualification without using a safe subset of the programming language. MISRA has been industry standard in automotive for ages - it started there, but is now de facto standard for pretty much all embedded systems. The 2012 version is much better than the 2004 one, in almost every aspect.

Comment: MISRA as a general concept is adopted for ages as you say, of course. I used it (older versions) for almost half of my life. However, I do not have recent information about the adoption of MISRA 2012, so I claim nothing about it.

Answer (score -2):

Not the most efficient way, but you can create a two dimensions array inside your function and copy the original array to it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int Filter(short* array, short nNumRow, short nNumCol) {
    short arr[nNumRow][nNumCol];
    memcpy(arr, array, nNumRow * nNumCol * sizeof(short));
    for (int i = 0; i < nNumRow; i++) {
        printf("| ");
        for (int j = 0; j < nNumCol; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("| \n");
    }
    return 0;

}

int main(void) {
    short arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8};
    Filter(arr, 2, 4);
    printf("---\n");
    Filter(arr, 4, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

See it running here: https://ideone.com/58KhYj